# What is the next higher order correction to Hooke's Law for a typical steel spring?

Tags: spring, anharmonic-oscillators

Near equilibrium the potential of a typical steel spring is well approximated by a quadratic function. I'm having trouble finding a reference for the what is the next-to-leading order contribution, and its magnitude, for typical spring-steel springs. For example if I want to predict the period of a mass on a spring for a clock, presumably I would want to compare the relative magnitudes of other various approximations such as air resistance, spring nonlinearity, etc. Is there a typical reference for this?

Comment: just taylor expand a general function of force around equilibrium point $f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+1/2f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2+...$  first term is zero obviously(at equilibrium $x=x_0$ force should be zero by definition of equilibrium) and near equlibrium that is $|x-x_0|<<1$ you can neglect higher terms which gives you hook's law.

Comment: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/young-modulus-d_417.html that would also help to actually calculate $f''$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus#:~:text=Young's%20modulus%20represents%20the%20factor,an%20elastic%20and%20linear%20response.&text=In%20solid%20mechanics%2C%20the%20slope,is%20called%20the%20tangent%20modulusthis shows how to calculate higher order terms using the young modulus of your spring and use

Comment: @physshyp, this doesn't answer my question. As I hopefully indicated by the wording of my question, I'm aware of the Taylor expansion leading order potential giving rise to Hooke's Law. This is useless without knowing the value of each coefficient for a given material. The links you give don't include any of the relevant constants for typical spring steel -- I'm hoping this is a common enough application to have a standard answer! Students across the world use steel springs in labs and measure T -- what is the NLO correction?

Comment: @physshyp, I can't find a functional form for E for spring steel (or any material for that matter), so I can't do an integral, nor do your links provide a table as a function of strain. I can find a table such that I could calculate a numerically integrated lookup table as a function of x. I guess my approach to find the NLO coefficient would be to fit an E table to a polynomial and integrate, but not being expert in this area, I'm worried I would be doing something stupid trying to reinvent the wheel for what is a thoroughly canonical problem. It's hardly obvious I should follow your advice.

Comment: you should download strain stress curve of steel than fit it to functional form thus you have youngs modulus of steel, using that calculate the young modulus of spring considering its length etc.

Comment: use materials database here https://mechanicalc.com/calculators/material-stress-strain-curve/

Comment: @physshyp, as best as I can tell from the data, the indication is that the NLO term would be exactly zero for small x, and the Ramberg-Osgood equation would imply a typical NLO coefficient order-of-magnitude of 10$^{-50}$. So either there is literally zero empirically measurable deviation from linearity for small oscillations of a steel spring in a lab (considering the material stress strain only, i.e. of course ignoring air resistance and other effects), or there is more to this story. If the former really is true, that is quite surprising, and deserves an authoritative reference.

Comment: no its not zero ofc there this regious before plastic region

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236020450_Friction_model_with_elasto-plasticity_in_transient_behavior/figures?lo=1

Comment: @physshyp, that link is about sliding friction, not springs. Even in this different context its mention of elasto-plasticity of the surface deformations show a linear regime is used with zero NLO correction, before transitioning to the non-linear regime.

Comment: see fig1 please

Comment: also i think it would be nice if you study this to get general understanding of this stuff, and I think on contrary to what you said this is not that simple question because highly non universal https://mechanicalc.com/reference/mechanical-properties-of-materials

Comment: @physshyp, figure 1 shows a piecewise perfectly linear "linear regime" with zero NLO, as I said, and therefore doesn't answer my question.